# WPF Combo Box Style

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, datatrigger

I have two combo boxes: **CarTypeComboBox** and **SeriesComboBox**.

Issues:
1. I want the **SeriesCombox** to be **visible** only when the user select **BMW**.
2. System.Windows.Style is showing up in **SeriesComboBox**.

Thank you

**Complete Code**:

```
    <Window x:Class="StyleTrigger.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StyleTrigger"
            xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:ComboBoxData"
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


        <Window.Resources >
            <local2:ComboBoxItemCollection x:Key="CarItemsCollection"/>

        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>



            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Label x:Name="CarBrand" Height="30" Width="75" Margin="10,0,0,0"  Content="Car Brand" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="CarTypeComboBox"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource CarItemsCollection}}" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="CarType" 
                        SelectedValuePath="CarID" 
                     />
            </StackPanel>


            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
                <Label x:Name="CarSeries" Height="30" Width="75" Margin="10,0,0,0"  Content="Car Series" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


                <ComboBox x:Name="SeriesComboBox"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="30"  
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <sys:String>230</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>280</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>530</sys:String>


                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">

                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.CarType, ElementName=CarTypeComboBox}" Value="BMW">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>




        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

C#

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ComboBoxData
        {
        class SingleComboBoxItem
            {
            public SingleComboBoxItem(int pCarID,String pCarBrand)
                {
                CarID = pCarID;
                CarType = pCarBrand;
                }

            public string CarType { get; set; }
            public int CarID { get; set; }

            }
        }


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ComboBoxData
        {
        class ComboBoxItemCollection : ObservableCollection<SingleComboBoxItem>
            {
            public ComboBoxItemCollection() : base()
                {
                Add(new SingleComboBoxItem(1,"Honda"));
                Add(new SingleComboBoxItem(2,"Toyota"));
                Add(new SingleComboBoxItem(3,"BMW"));
                Add(new SingleComboBoxItem(4,"Dodge"));
                Add(new SingleComboBoxItem(5,"Lexus"));
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The SeriesComboBox is not appearing when I select BMW.

Comment: This would be much easier if you pasted in the whole XAML for your ComboBox, rather than scattering decontextualized fragments around your question and expecting us to guess what goes where in your actual code. H.B.'s answer is probably correct, but I can't be certain.

Comment: Ed: I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm having issues pasting code in the comment.

Comment: Don't post code in comments -_-

Comment: Don't paste code in the comment. Paste it in the question. You can edit your own question all you like, just click the "edit" link below the row of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ComboBox style should look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
  <!-- Just add this one Setter -->
  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.CarType, ElementName=CarTypeComboBox}" Value="BMW">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Do not set the `Visibility` attribute on the `ComboBox` tag itself. No `Visibility="Hidden"` on the `ComboBox`. That will override the style setters and it will *never* be visible. ONLY set `Visibility` in setters in the style.

## UPDATE

Now that I've seen the whole code, I can offer a little more insight. First, you said "The SeriesComboBox is not appearing when I select BMW.", but what's happening in the version you just posted is that it is not *disappearing* when you *don't* select BMW. Now, let's take a look at what it does do:

[image]

There's an anomaly in that dropdown list: The last item is `System.Windows.Style`. I'm willing to bet you haven't ever seen that model of BMW on the road any more than I have.

Your `Style` is correctly defined, and I think it may have been correct even before we started hassling you about it. The trouble is you aren't assigning it to the `Style` property of the `ComboBox`. Instead you're adding it to the default content property, which in the case of `ComboBox` is `Items`. In WPF, you can throw *literally almost figuratively just about anything at all* in a `ComboBox` (or `ListBox`) items collection. It's a collection of `object`. It'll eat any old garbage you feed it and never complain. Since you didn't specify `DisplayMemberPath` for that one, it just cheerfully calls `ToString()` on each object in turn.

So to assign the style to the `Style` property of the `ComboBox`, put it inside `<ComboBox.Style>`:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="SeriesComboBox"  
    Margin="10,0,0,0" 
    Width="100" 
    Height="30"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <sys:String>230</sys:String>
    <sys:String>280</sys:String>
    <sys:String>530</sys:String>

    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.CarType, ElementName=CarTypeComboBox}" 
                    Value="BMW"
                    >
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

You could also define the `Style` in `Resources`, give it `x:Key="SeriesComboBoxStyle"`, and set the `Style` attribute on the `ComboBox` tag: `Style="{StaticResource SeriesComboBoxStyle}"`.

Comment: @NewUser I don't trust you; you keep changing your story about what's in your XAML. Maybe you're setting Visibility in an attriubute. Maybe the selected item in `CarTypeComboBox` doesn't have a `CarType` property, or it's never equal to "BMW", or `CarTypeComboBox` isn't actually the name of that ComboBox. You didn't post anything that reproduces the issue, so nobody can help you.

Comment: I have update my post with complete code. Ed: It doesn't mean if I'm a new user you should not trust  me :)

Comment: @NewUser Updated with solution.

Comment: Thank you Ed. Hope you trust me now ;).                                                        Is there anything else I should do to close the question other than mark it as Correct ?

Comment: Ed: Do you think referencing other combo boxes is a good practice when defining the style in Windows.Resources ?

Comment: @NewUser In this particular case, I wouldn't define that style in Resources, and that's the reason -- unless for some reason I had two comboboxes which both let the user select a series for BMW.

Comment: @NewUser As a rule, though, I would have a viewmodel, and I would have SeriesComboBox looking at `SelectedCar.CarType` on the viewmodel rather than looking at the other combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional `Setter` with the default value `Hidden` **to the `Style` itself**, not the triggers.

Comment: I have added <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/> to the Style still does not work,

Comment: Use your brain, the trigger should set it to `Visible`.

Comment: That's what you recommended in your comment.

Comment: Well, if you did not mess up the [precedences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) that should work.